# How to sort load order/load exclusion of javascript files to Laravel Asset Pipeline?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am using Laravel Assets Pipeline(https://github.com/CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline) plugin for the my project.

I have managed to set it up working but 2 issues pop up:

- I have a backend and a frontend area, both needing different js files. When I configure the paths where he should look for the js files, he will include all of them on both directories. Even if I set different manifest files, each in his own frontend of backend asset directory, he will get all the files on path.
- When loading the js files, because he loads them by script name order, he will get bootstrap.js before jquery.js and similar, causing errors on the scripts.

Has anyone figured out solutions for these issues ?

Here is my config.app paths:

```
'paths' => array(
    'app/assets/back/fonts',
    'app/assets/back/images',
    'app/assets/back/stylesheets',
    'app/assets/back/javascripts',
    'app/assets/front/stylesheets',
    'app/assets/front/fonts',
    'app/assets/front/images',
    'app/assets/front/javascripts',
    'lib/assets/fonts',
    'lib/assets/images',
    'lib/assets/javascripts',
    'lib/assets/stylesheets',
    'provider/assets/fonts',
    'provider/assets/images',
    'provider/assets/stylesheets',
    'provider/assets/javascripts'
),
```

and my javascripts.blade.php on the frontend:

```
    <!-- JS -->
    @javascripts('app/assets/front/javascripts/application')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. Turns out this Assets Pipeline was built around how RoR manages it's assets (http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline?view=asciicast).

After much trial and error, following the cast above, I managed to change my directory structure and created the necessary files to load everything right.